# How to calculate the relation ship graph between people?

Tags: algorithm, graph, social-networking

In this web page [EntityCube](http://entitycube.research.microsoft.com/Guanxi.aspx) we can type in a person's name then we will get a relationship graph describing the social network of this person, for example we type in bill gates we will get like this:
[image]

Does anybody know the algorithm behind this?

Comment: Warren buffet is twice!!

Comment: Indeed a problem! Maybe two different persons? I cannot think of another Buffet so famous.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little ambiguous, but I'll try to answer it as best I can.  The graph they are producing shows only the people directly linked to the "source" (Bill Gates) and the relationships between those people.

The website probably contains a graph that includes everyone.  Let's assume for the sake of argument that they are using an adjacency list (each person has a list of their "friends").

When you type in Bill Gates, it goes through each of his friends and connects them to him.  Then it goes through the adjacency lists of each friend and checks to see if each friend is also a friend of Bill Gates.  If so, it then connects them.  Otherwise it ignores that friend and continues.

Comment: But some people are far from bill gates, some are near to him. This algorithm doesn't capture this notion.

Comment: Ah.  That's what I mean about the ambiguity - I wasn't sure exactly what you were asking.  The graph might be weighted, but I don't know what the distance actually means (if anything).  Same with the color.  Jerry Seinfield and Linux Torvalds are the same color, for example, and I can't think of any possible reason for that.  By the way, if you didn't notice the entitycube has an about page with links to research papers: http://entitycube.research.microsoft.com/readme.htm

Comment: To be honest, i didn't notice it in the first place, thx anyway!